# Google Sheets Find Previously Created Sheet Using Name

Tags: python, google-sheets

My use-case is to use a script to create/update a sheet on my google drive and have it run everyday so the data is correct.

My code properly creates the sheet, but when I run each day it creates a different sheet with the same name.  I want to add a try, except to see if the sheet was previously, and if it is, just overwrite.

I've spent a couple of hours trying to find an example where someone did this.  I'm looking to return the sheetid, whether it's newly created or previously created.

```
def create_spreadsheet(sp_name, creds):
  proxy = None

  #Connect to sheet API
  sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http(proxy_info = proxy)))

  #create spreadsheet with title 'sp_title'
  sp_title = sp_name

  spreadsheet_req_body = {
    'properties': {
      'title': sp_title
    }
  }
  spreadsheet = sheets_service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet_req_body,
                                    fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
  return spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a method that you can list your spreadsheets and get their ids. If you need the Spreadsheet Ids you created earlier, just save it to a sheet with the ID and creation date (when successful).

Comment: I don't know if I understand you well, but you can use the google drive api to list your spreadsheets if that's what you need.

Comment: I would need it to list the id's and title.  Like you mentioned I could also create a google sheet, with google sheet ids in it.  Seems crazy to have to do that.

Comment: You can use the Drive API to list the Id and Title of your spreadsheets. you can try here : https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to check whether the file (Spreadsheet), which has the specific filename, is existing in your Google Drive.
- If the file is existing, you want to return the file ID of it.
- If the file is not existing, you want to return the file ID by creating new Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve above using google-api-python-client of Python.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? There is the method for confirming whether the file, which has the specific filename, is existing using Drive API. In this modification, the method of Files: list Drive API is used. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- In this modification, the method of Files: list Drive API is used. The file is checked with the search query.

  - In this case, the file is searched by the filename and the mimeType and out of the trash box.
  - When the file is existing, the file ID is return.
  - When the file is NOT existing, new Spreadsheet is created and return the file ID by your script.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

```
def create_spreadsheet(sp_name, creds):
    proxy = None
    sp_title = sp_name

    # --- I added blow script.
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http(proxy_info = proxy)))
    q = "name='%s' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed=false" % sp_title
    files = drive_service.files().list(q=q).execute()
    f = files.get('files')
    if f:
        return f[0]['id']
    # ---

    sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http(proxy_info = proxy)))
    sp_title = sp_name

    spreadsheet_req_body = {
        'properties': {
            'title': sp_title
        }
    }
    spreadsheet = sheets_service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet_req_body,
                                                       fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
    return spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, I used `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` as the scope. So please enable Drive API and add the scope and delete the file including the access token and refresh token, then please authorize the scopes by running the script, again. By this, the additional scope can be reflected to the access token. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks.  Huge help!

Comment: @nonegiven72 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.